# tail -v a file while excluding a list of words

Tags: grep, tail

I'd like to tail a log file that's continuously being written to but would like to exclude various entries that are 'common' so I only see errors, etc. as they are thrown.  I can pipe to grep -v "pattern" but would ideally like to use a file containing entries to skip.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `grep -v "pattern"` like you said. But instead of `pattern` use

```
`cat file_with_entires_to_skip`
```

Remember to include the backtics. So your command would look like:

```
tail -v FILE | grep -v "`cat FILE_WITH_ENTRIES_TO_SKIP`"
```

Comment: Make that grep -v "`cat FILE_WITH_ENTRIES_TO_SKIP`", or the shell will expand special characters in the pattern list.

Comment: You mean `grep -v "\`cat FILE_WITH_ENTIRES_TO_SKIP\`"`? (You have to escape backtics in Markdown.)

Answer (score 2):

The `-f` option to `grep` allows one to specify a file containing patterns, one pattern per line.  See the `grep(1)` man page.

In addition, the `unbuffer` command available on some systems will disable the output buffering that normally occurs in pipelines.  The addition of the `grep` filter may otherwise delay the output of your pipeline.  See the `unbuffer(1)` man page for details.

Comment: You might mention that you need both -f and -v for the given requirements.

Comment: It sounds like they are looking to exclude specific results, not patterns, so a fixed-string search (-F) would be more appropriate.

I'd go with `tail -v [file_to_tail] | grep -Fvf [file_with_list_of_lines_to_exclude]`

Answer (score 1):

My grep includes an `--exclude-from=FILE` option that lets me add exclusion patterns from a file. I've got:

```
my-macbook-pro:Sun America ianchesal$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

So you could do:

```
tail -f <file> | grep --exclude-from=excludes.txt
```

Comment: "Skip  files  whose base name matches any of the file-name globs read from FILE (using wildcard matching as described under
              --exclude)." So it's for skipping files, not matches

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -f FILE` and it will obtain patterns from that file. See the [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: grep -v -f EXCLUDE_FILENAME_LIST TARGET_FILENAME

EXCLUDE_FILENAME_LIST = List of words you want to grep out of your search
TARGET_FILENAME = The Primary file you wish to grep